# Error deploying python flask app on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, sentiment-analysis

I try to host my python flask app on heroku but my requirements file seems not to install successfully, please i need help

Collecting ml-dtypes==0.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 42))
Downloading ml_dtypes-0.2.0.tar.gz (698 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
     × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
     │ exit code: 1
     ╰─> [56 lines of output]
         Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.11"' don't match your environment
         Collecting numpy~=1.23.3
           Downloading numpy-1.23.5.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
              ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.7/10.7 MB 82.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
           Installing build dependencies: started
           Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
           Getting requirements to build wheel: started
           Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
           error: subprocess-exited-with-error
         
           × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
           │ exit code: 1
           ╰─> [33 lines of output]
               Traceback (most recent call last):
                 File "/tmp/build_be91dd7a/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
                   main()
                 File "/tmp/build_be91dd7a/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
                   json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 File "/tmp/build_be91dd7a/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
                   backend = _build_backend()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 File "/tmp/build_be91dd7a/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
                   obj = import_module(mod_path)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
                   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
                 File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p2mhgdo_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
                   import setuptools.version
                 File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p2mhgdo_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
                   import pkg_resources
                 File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p2mhgdo_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
                   register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
               [end of output]
         
           note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
         
         × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
         │ exit code: 1
         ╰─> See above for output.
         
         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
         [end of output]
     
     note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
   
   × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
   │ exit code: 1
   ╰─> See above for output.
   
   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

I had run exact code in my local environment and it works well, i only pushed to github and tried to host on heroku